# How to indent the equation number a bit to the left?

Tags: equations, numbering, amsmath

How can I add space after the equation numbering?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    a = b + c
  \end{align} 
\end{document}
```

So I want to move the equation number a little bit more to the left:

```
a = b + c                                                     (1)   <--   (1)
```

EDIT/SOLUTION: I could adjust my code thanks to barbara beeton:

```
\makeatletter
\def\tagform@#1{\maketag@@@{(#1)\unskip\@@italiccorr}\hspace{2em}}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the `\unskip`, you're undoing the intentional `\hspace`.

remove that, or, better still, put the `\hspace` at the end, and you should get
the result you want.

Comment: Stupid me... thank you! Updated code can be found above...